# How do I filter out CLOSED items older than a certain age on export

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I've been trying to figure out how to filter out older CLOSED items when exporting by org tasks. I thought I should be able to use [org-export-get-date](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-export-reference.html#get-date) with information from the communications channel in a *:filter-headline* filter but I haven't been able to get it to work. It's not helped by the comms channel structure being so massive you can't print it out without hanging *ielm*. Do I just need to extract the the start and end bounds of the entry and furtle around for the closed tag myself?